# With a generalized linear model, what are the criteria for an effect being estimable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, interaction

This seems like a simple thing but it dawned on me I did not really know how to answer this. What are the criteria for being able to estimate an effect?

For example, with the data set:

```
dat<-structure(list(Y = c(100L, 556L, 25L, 32L, 15L, 56L, 95L, 455L, 253L, 355L, 422L, 45L, 458L), A = c(526L, 241L, 26L, 12L, 266L, 225L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Y", "A", "B1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-13L))
dat 


     Y   A B1
1  100 526  1
2  556 241  1
3   25  26  1
4   32  12  1
5   15 266  1
6   56 225  1
7   95   0  0
8  455   0  0
9  253   0  0
10 355   0  0
11 422   0  0
12  45   0  0
13 458   0  0
```

How would you explain why an A*B1 interaction can't be estimated?

Comment: The criteria for a GLM aren't any different than for any other linear model: collinearity creates lack of estimability because then the model has redundant parameters.

Comment: So, the fact that A and A*B1 are identical. Is there anything to be said about it in terms of the variability or lack thereof in the A and B1 columns? In other words can you think about the regression of Y~A on a subset of B1 == 1 versus B1 ==0 to immediately see that no variation on A exists when B1 ==0?

Comment: Everything comes back to collinearity. I'm unsure what you mean by "variability or lack thereof." All I can do is appeal to the definitions: with $k$ variables $x_i, i=1,\ldots,k$, if there exist $k$ coefficients $\alpha_i$, not all zero, for which $\alpha_1x_1+\cdots+\alpha_kx_k=0$, then there is lack of estimability (precisely because at least one of the $x_i$ can be expressed in terms of the remaining ones); and lack of estimability implies such a relation must hold. This is because all predictions in the GLM depend *only* on linear combinations of the $x_i$, just as in multiple regression.

Comment: And just to point out the obvious, *effect* $\neq$ *causal effect*. With GLM, you're estimating a conditional expectation function, and these effects may or may not be causal. Additional conditions are required to estimate causal effets (compared to what is necessary to simply estimate a conditional expectation function). High levels of police may predict high levels of crime, but that of course doesn't imply that police cause crime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that $AB$ is a linear combination of other regressors (in this case, simply $AB = A$), hence including $A$ and $AB$ would make your regression suffer from multicollinearity. $AB$ is not distinguishable in a linear model from $A$.

Many situations can give rise to collinear regressors. For fun, I'm going to name the variables:

- Let $B$ be an indicator variable denoting the winter.
- Let $A$ be furnace usage.
- Let $Y$ be your utility bill.

In your example, all your furnace usage occurs during the winter, hence furnace usage (i.e. $A$) and furnace usage during the winter (i.e. $AB$) are the same thing.

Collinearity of course can be a little less obvious. For example:

- Let $a$ be a child's current age.
- Let $s$ be a child's years of schooling.
- Let $c$ be the age a child first start school.

Among school children, these are collinear because for someone still in school, $a - c = s$. (And if everyone starts school at the same age, then $a$ and $s$ and a constant are collinear.)